# Query match without score in elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I would like to simply match value of the field and I dont care about score (it will return always one match). I dont want elasticsearch to create me a score which may result on worse performance... or I am wrong and I should not care?

Simple query like this:

```
GET /testing/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "My name here",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I expect one result with no score (and I dont want to use filtered).

Comment: if you want a exact match of a field value you may want consider a term query. Regarding the score have a look here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html

Answer (score 1):

You could override the default similarity with a custom one that just spits out a constant score for all matches.  See the ElasticSearch documentation on [how to set the Similarity module](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html)

However, for a query just involving a simple exact match on a term or phrase, the performance impact is unlikely to be significant.  Profiling might help determine if this is really worth pursuing.